# How to do an app logout using nodejs and okta

Tags: node.js, angular, express, openid-connect, okta

I am currently using Okta with OIDC and Node Express to log into a web app that I made. I want my users to be able to logout of just my app and not okta itself as the okta is for my company and that would log them out of all the other websites that use the company okta. Okta recommends doing this on their website.

```
app.get('/local-logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

(https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-users-out/nodeexpress/sign-out-of-your-app/)

I have tried implementing this but it doesn't work. I have also tried using req.session.destroy, res.clearCookie("connect.sid"), req.session = null and many different combinations of these with or without callbacks. Whenever I redirect, it just goes back to the homepage and the same user is logged in. Whenever I try deleting the connect.sid cookie it deletes and then is reinitialized when the user is redirected. I'm not really sure what to do. My code with irrelevant endpoints removed is below.

```
require('dotenv').config();

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { join } from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync, read } from 'fs';


// 30 minutes
const sessionMaxAge = 1800000;

import * as e from 'cors';
import { resolveForwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '@okta/okta-sdk-nodejs';

const session = require('express-session');
const { ExpressOIDC } = require('@okta/oidc-middleware');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");


 /** Creates the OpenID Connect Middleware and configures it to work with Okta */
 const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
  appBaseUrl: process.env.HOST_URL,
  issuer: `${process.env.OKTA_ORG_URL}/oauth2/default`,
  client_id: process.env.OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: process.env.OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URL,
  scope: 'openid profile',
  routes: {
    loginCallback: {
      path: '/authorization-code/callback'
    },
  }
});


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  var root_folder: string = process.env.ROOT_FOLDER || "dist/angular-app/browser"
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), root_folder);
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__github.com_angular_universal_tree_master_modules_express-2Dengine&d=DwIGAg&c=-35OiAkTchMrZOngvJPOeA&r=03NdPO1x-l0QAZ_R9TNGwA&m=WF5ia-YADjCituVWMV5vLoZ5wg7d_W1qhCYDTbJNGT0&s=WPOkeRsetPDQ6TrD26RKLo1m9_zxBfQXGhUUSkth0Ew&e= )
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder); 

  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // Configure Session Support
  server.use( session({
      secret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {maxAge: sessionMaxAge}
    })
  );
  
  server.use(cookieParser());
  server.use(oidc.router);

   // Log the user out of the local session
   server.get('/local-logout',(req:any, res:any) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', oidc.ensureAuthenticated({ redirectTo: '/login' }), (req: any, res: any) => {
    if(req.session && req.session.username != null) {
      console.log(process.env);
      res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
    }
    else {
      console.log("getting user info");
      getUserInfo(req)
      .then(userInfo => {
        req.session.username = userInfo.username;
        req.session.group = userInfo.group;
        if (userInfo.group=="unauthorized") {
          res.sendFile('./403.html', {root: "."})
        }
        else{
          console.log(process.env);
          res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
        }
      });
  }
  });

  return server;
}
  function run(): void {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    // Start up the Node server
    const server = app();
    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Node Express server listening on https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__localhost-3A-24-257Bport-257D&d=DwIGAg&c=-35OiAkTchMrZOngvJPOeA&r=03NdPO1x-l0QAZ_R9TNGwA&m=WF5ia-YADjCituVWMV5vLoZ5wg7d_W1qhCYDTbJNGT0&s=PUb7XMS4uP9ICqUY28QgXNRxoWk6sGatPdmZMqmgbJs&e= `);
    });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an exhaustive search, I don't think it is possible. I ended up doing `req.logout()` and then redirecting to a page that says "you have been logged out of the app but may still be logged into your single sign on provider."